# New iterations not showing up in ADO dashboard's burndown widget?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Running into a problem in ADO where I can't get my current iteration to show up as an option in my dashboard's sprint burndown widget. My iterations show up as desired in my projects settings and I am able to see and assign from all my user stories. However, when I attempt to set my sprint burndown widget, only these three appear. I've even tried deleting these three and add three new ones with different names, yet these three remain. Note that new iterations don't show up, only these three.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screeshot, the list of the iterations are for the whole project(**Project Settings-> Project Configuration**) instead of the selected team.

To solve this issue, you could refer to the following steps:

Step1: Check the selected Team in the widget.

[image]

Step2: Navigate to **Project Settings -> Team Configuration-> Iteration**, select the team and add the existing iterations.

[image]

Then you could see all iterations in the widget list.

**Update:**

I could reproduce your situation.

Based on my test, the sprint burndown widget will display the current iteration (date) and the previous iteration. Future iterations will not appear in the widget until the start date is reached.

For example:

Team Iteration:

[image]

Current date: 8/23. It will show est3(passed) and est iteration (current).

[image]

From you screenshot, you can check if week34 and week35 exists in the dropdown list.

Comment: It doesn't work and appears to match the settings you've described. I will note that my team settings (and project) don't have those iterations that appear in in the widget settings. (Updated screengrabs in original post.)

Comment: @Layne Can you check if week34 and week35 exists in the dropdown list? Please check my update.

Comment: Your update is accurate. However, the problem is that @CurrentIteration is stuck on my "Week 33." There is no option to select "Week 34" (last week) or "Week 35" (current week/current iteration). It just stops at 33. (Note that it also still shows a "Week 31" and "Week 32" which were deleted some time ago.) It's almost like the widget is stuck at a moment in time from from three weeks ago and is never updating with changes: additions, subtractions, nothing.

Comment: When I say, "Note that it also still shows a "Week 31" and "Week 32" which were deleted some time ago." I mean that's what displays in the "Select iteration" dropdown of the widget, not the screengrab I posted above.